# A button to count the number of times it has been clicked in one minute

Tags: java, swing

Hey i am trying to build a program using swing. I have created a button and I want to count the number of times it is clicked in one minute.But the problem is that once I press said button it does not get released and the counter keeps on increasing on its own.
Code:

```
    while ((System.currentTimeMillis()-startTime)< 1*60*1000)
    {   
        if(eee.getSource()==b)
            {
                counter++;  

            }
        System.out.println(counter);
    }
```

Comment: you can either put the count/timing in a separate thread or you can measure start/time each time you click - if it's later than one minute, then it doesn't count anymore...

Comment: have you tried replacing while with if?

Comment: The way your code is written, it tries to increment `counter` as much as possible (by the processor) within 1 minute...

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of "Honey, I stopped the Event Dispatching Thread". Swing is a singled threaded framework, you can't use long running loops, `Thread.sleep` or blocking processes while executing in it...

Answer (score 2):

Lets start with basics...

Swing is a single threaded environment, anything that stops the Event Dispatching Thread from running, prevents the it from updating the UI or responding to other events.  Equally, you should only ever modify the state of UI components from within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread.

Have a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

For a simple example, this simply allows you to click the button, on each click it determines if a minute has passed or not, if it hasn't it updates the state of the button

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class SmackMe {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SmackMe();
    }

    public static final long ONE_MINUTE = 1000 * 60;

    private long startTime = -1;
    private int count = 0;

    public SmackMe() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JButton button = new JButton("Smack me");
                button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        if (startTime < 0) {
                            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        }
                        long diff = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
                        System.out.println((diff / 1000));
                        if (diff >= ONE_MINUTE) {
                            startTime = -1;
                            button.setEnabled(false);
                        } else {
                            count++;
                        }
                        button.setText(Integer.toString(count));
                    }
                });

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
                frame.add(button);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

The problem with this, is it is responsive, it needs the button to be clicked in order to perform the time check, a better solution would have some kind of background process which could disable the button after one minute...

This is a perfect use case for `javax.swing.Timer`...

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class SmackMe {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SmackMe();
    }

    public static final int ONE_MINUTE = 1000 * 60;

    private int count = 0;
    private Timer timer;
    private JButton button;

    public SmackMe() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                button = new JButton("Smack me");
                button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        if (!timer.isRunning()) {
                            timer.start();
                        }
                        count++;
                        button.setText(Integer.toString(count));
                    }
                });

                timer = new Timer(ONE_MINUTE, new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        button.setEnabled(false);
                    }
                });
                timer.setRepeats(false);

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
                frame.add(button);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Take a look at [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more details...